Printing a list without nil on common lisp
I am still stuck whit this. I'm trying to print a list of elements that are between two limits in Common Lisp. I wrote two functions to do this. In the first one I check if the element is inside the limits. The second one is only to run this check on a list. I got the result I'm looking for but it's printed whit a nil when the element is not in the conditions. How can I print this list of elements whitout the nil word?
(defun limits (x) 
  (if (or (< x 3) (> x 12))
      (nconc x)
      ()))

(defun out-of-limits (l) 
  (mapcar #'limits l)
  (remove nil))


(out-of-limits '(1 7 8 2 5 1 215))

  ----> (1 NIL NIL 2 NIL 1 215)



errata: (remove nil) was removed after this question was posted

@M1ctl4nt3cutl1 "....was removed after this question was posted"  Why did you not use the [edit] functionality ?

Here are some hints:
(defun limits (x) 
  (if (or (< x 3) (> x 12))
      (nconc x)              ; why is NCONC here???
      ()))

(defun out-of-limits (l) 
  (mapcar #'limits l)        ; This value is never used
  (remove nil))              ; REMOVE needs more arguments

You are calling REMOVE with one argument: the thing to be removed. REMOVE requires two arguments. Where is the missing argument? From what do you want to remove it?
NCONC is an operation to concatenate lists. But you are calling it on a single number? What's the idea behind that? Is a number a list? Definitely not.
(mapcar #'limits l) returns a list. But your function out-of-limits doesn't do anything with the result list. Why? The result list is never used. It is not returned from the function out-of-limits and it is not used by other functions. Why do you compute a list, which is never used for anything?

Start by rewriting your limits function to just return true or false if its argument is in range. I'd give it a better name too, following the Common Lisp tradition of functions that test something having names ending in p for predicate:
;;; Note the change in logic to return t if a number is IN a given range, not
;;; outside of it.
(defun in-range-p (x)
  (<= 3 x 12))

Then your out-of-limits function can use that predicate and standard list operations to return a list of just the elements that pass the test (mapcar doesn't do any filtering; there are more suitable functions that do).
One approach, using loop:
(defun out-of-limits (l)
  (loop for elem in l
        unless (in-range-p elem)
          collect elem))

or using the remove-if higher order function:
(defun out-of-limits (l)
  (remove-if #'in-range-p l))

With either of these definitions, (out-of-limits '(1 7 8 2 5 1 215)) returns the list (1 2 1 215)
